# Execute a command after tmux split pane

Tags: tmux

When we do <kbd>C+a</kbd> or whatever key binding is and followed by `"` or `%` then tmux split this pane into horizontally or vertically.

What I want is whenever I press <kbd>C+a+%</kbd> or <kbd>C+a+"</kbd> then it should execute some command.

e.g. <kbd>C+a+%</kbd> should split the pane and execute command `ls` and <kbd>C+a+"</kbd> should split the pane and execute the command `ls` in the same pane.

You can assume always  I want to execute the same command e.g `ls`.

How to achieve this in tmux using tmux.conf file?

Comment: Do you want the command to be run as if you typed it in the new terminal/pane, or do you want to capture output in copy mode and then discard it once the command has run?

Comment: I don't want to capture o/p of command, I want to run another command which doesn't produce any output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To split the widow horizontally and make the command `ls -al` run as if you typed it in the new terminal/pane

```
bind-key '"' split-window \; send-keys "ls -al" Enter
```

for a vertical split

```
bind-key % split-window -h \; send-keys "ls -al" Enter
```

To split horizontal and run the command in the background then capture the output in copy mode

```
bind-key " split-window \; run-shell "ls -al"
```

The `\;` is used to quote the `"` intended for the `split-window` command from the `bind-key` command.

Comment: This seems not to be working, specially for ".

Comment: For the doublequote version you need to singlequote the character, i.e. it begins `bind-key '"' split-window...`.

Comment: @meuh ,thanks, I tested the command on my computer by binding  `,` (I didn't want to break my `"` binding) the command worked for me, so I assumed it would be good to post!

Comment: Interestingly after adding `bind-key '"' split-window \; send-keys "ls -al" Enter` and  `bind-key % split-window \; send-keys "ls -al" Enter` both splits horizontally pane instead of splitting horizontally and vertically.

Comment: @sonukumar: for horizontal split its missing the `-h` argument: have a look into `man tmux`, for the `split-window -h`: 
_-h does a horizontal split and -v a vertical split; if neither is specified, -v is assumed_